# Передать значение из одного SELECT в SQL-запрос другого SELECT

Tags: java, html, jsp

Имеется SELECT со списком умений

```
 <sql:query var="priv_query">
  SELECT code from skills
  </sql:query>
            
<select name="group_code" id="group_code">
 <c:forEach var="row" items="${priv_query.rows}">
 <option value="${row.code}" selected >${row.code}</option>
</c:forEach>
 </select>
```

Необходимо, чтобы пользователь, выбравший определенный скилл в первом SELECT, мог выбрать уже во втором SELECT предпочтения.

Я сделал следующим образом:

Написал цикл для добавления значений с первого SELECT

```
<c:set var="formid_list" value="" />
<c:forEach items="${priv_query.rows}" var="row">
    <c:set var="formid_list" value="${row.code}" />
    <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

И в следующий запрос должны попадать значения:

```
<sql:query var="itemquery">
   select skname from sf_skills where code IN (${formid_list})
</sql:query>
```

Для второго SELECT у меня следующий код:

```
<select name="code" id="code">
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${itemquery.rows}">
            <option value="${row.skillname}" selected >${row.skillname}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

Берется только последнее значение ${formid_list} при заходе на страницу, а при выборе другого ничего не происходит. Как можно исправить код так, чтобы пользователь мог выбирать значения из первого SELECT, а значения ${formid_list} попадали в реальном времени в sql-запрос второго SELECT?